# React Component div id will not hide what used in map loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have this code in an index.html file which loads with the application:

```
$(window).on('load', () => {
    $('#one').hide();
    $('#oneb').hide();
});
```

And this affects the component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Test = (props) => <div id="MyDiv">


    <div>

        <div id="one">
            THIS IS ONE
        </div>


        {

            props.list.map((data, i) => {

                return <div id="oneb" key={i}>
                   THIS IS ONEB
                </div>

            })

        }


    </div>
</div>
```

What is happening here is that div with id="one" will hide BUT id="oneb" will still show up.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: How many elements are in `props.entitlements`? Is it rendering multiple elements with the same id?

Comment: Renamed it to list ... and it could be one or 10

Comment: Don't use an Id if it will be duplicated on the page, the html spec dictates that an elements Id must be unique for a document. I'm not sure if this will be affecting the behaviour you are seeing but as the answer says, this is a non-react way of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing it the React way. To do it the React way, your component should hold and manipulate some kind of state. Check the example below:

```
import React from 'react';
class MyAwesomeComponent React.Component {
    constructor(){
        this.state = {
            hide: false
        }
    }
    render(){
        const {hide} = this.state;

        <React.Fragment>
            {
                hide
                ? null
                : <div>This is my awesome div that I need to show or hide ;)</div>
            }
            <button>{hide ? 'Show': 'Hide'}</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    }
}
export default MyAwesomeComponent;
```

The code above will hide or show your div. Check the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org)